# gRPC code from non-Razor file in Blazor client-side never completes

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor Client hosted in ASP.Net Core. In the Server project, I have a gRPC service. Protos are stored in a Shared project (referenced by both Server and Client).

This works successfully if I call it from a .razor file. I set up the client in the startup.ConfigureServices -

```
services.AddSingleton(services =>
        {
            // Create a gRPC-Web channel pointing to the backend server
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
            var baseUri = services.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>().BaseUri;
            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseUri, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });

            // Now we can instantiate gRPC clients for this channel
            return new Abilities.AbilitiesClient(channel);
        });
```

Inject it into the razor page -

```
@inject Abilities.AbilitiesClient AbilitiesClient
```

And load the collection on init -

```
private IList<Ability> abilities;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    abilities = (await AbilitiesClient.GetAbilitiesAsync(new Empty())).Abilities;
}
```

Works no problem! But I don't want to cram all of this logic into the view as I have over a dozen different services, so I've moved it out to a helper class. Now instead of adding the client to the services at startup, I add the helper -

```
services.AddSingleton(services =>
{
    return new Helpers.gRPCHelper(services.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>().BaseUri);
});
```

In the helper's constructor, I throw the base URI into a private variable, so I can spin up the channel on demand. In the function that calls the gRPC service, I have the below -

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(_BaseURI, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });
var abilityClient = new Abilities.AbilitiesClient(channel);
Console.WriteLine("Calling gRPC");             
var abilities = abilityClient.GetAbilities(new Empty(), null).Abilities;
Console.WriteLine("Call Complete");
```

In the browsers console, I see the "Calling gRPC", but the "Call Complete" is never logged. The browser just sits, waiting, I gave up after 5 minutes.

On the server side, I can see the gRPC method being called, I can even hit a break point in it and verify that it is successfully completing with results.

I don't see the traffic in the web browser's network tab (neither Chrome nor Edge).

I tried setting a deadline of 10 seconds, but it never popped.

This is all off the preview releases. So I'm not sure if I'm running into a current limitation, or if I'm doing something wrong -

```
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client.Web" Version="2.27.0-dev202001100801" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.1.0-preview4.19579.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.1.0-preview4.19579.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.1.0-preview4.19579.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer" Version="3.1.0-preview4.19579.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Mono" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20052.1" />
```

Sever output -

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://localhost:44340/Ability.Abilities/GetAbilities application/grpc-web 5
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'gRPC - /Ability.Abilities/GetAbilities'
********************************************************************
GetAbilities Called!
********************************************************************
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.1 initialized 'Context' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (143ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a].[AbilityID], [a].[Icon], [a].[LongText], [a].[ShortText], [a].[Source], [a].[Title]
      FROM [Abilities] AS [a]
      ORDER BY [a].[Title]
********************************************************************
GetAbilities Complete!
********************************************************************
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'gRPC - /Ability.Abilities/GetAbilities'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 3555.6284ms 200 application/grpc-web
```

Poked around at this a bit more last night and I'm seeing another oddity. As soon as the client makes the gRPC call, the browser starts sucking up CPU, 25-35%. Edge will eventually pop a 'long running script' error. Chrome effectively hangs and has to be forcibly closed. I'm starting to think the project may be borked, I'll try building a fresh simplified implementation to see if I can get it working in a slimmed down code base.

Comment: Updated references to 3.2. Still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Why do you call `GetAbilities` in your helper class and `GetAbilitiesAsync` before you refactor the code ? I guess the sync version hang and you should swap to the async version.

Comment: Good thought, but same behavior. :(

Comment: The log on your client is really weird, it's like you try to call the gRPC method on your client but not on the server.

Comment: Looks like it was something to do with the async call. I made a stripped down sample (https://github.com/ThatRickGuy/WASM-Blazor-gRPC-Sample) and can recreate the behavior by switching between async and sync gRPC calls.